# Transform \n to new line although input variable is single quoted in Puppet

Tags: puppet

If a variable is double quoted and it contains a `\n`

```
$test="hello\nworld"

file { '/tmp/hello':
        content => $test
}
```

then a new line is created:

```
/tmp/hello
hello
world
```

**Problem**

What to do if the input is not double quoted due to hiera input or regsubst outcome:

```
$test2=hiera("hiera::input")

file { '/tmp/hello':
        content => $test2
}
```

results in:

```
hello\nworld
```

**Attempt to solve the issue**

The assumption was that double quoting the content variable would solve the issue. Neither:

```
file { '/tmp/hello':
        content => "$test2"
}
```

nor:

```
file { '/tmp/hello':
        content => "\"$test2\""
}
```

solves the issue. The latter results in:

```
"hello\nworld"
```

**Second attempt**

Another attempt was tried after reading [this answer at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com.80bola.com/a/29144823).

*hiera.yaml*

```
---
bla: haha\nblabla
```

*manifest file*

```
$test=hiera('bla')

$quoted = regsubst($test, '(.*)', '"\1"')

file { '/tmp/hello':
        content => $quoted
}
```

results in:

```
"haha\nblabla"
```

Comment: How does this apply to a real use case? why can't you just copy the file over or use a template?

Comment: I do not want to change the module every time

Comment: That's what templates are for.

Comment: An erb template will `\n` translate to a new line always and it does not matter whether the variable is single or double quoted? I will test it.

Comment: Using an erb template does not solve the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are using Hiera's YAML backend but I am sure the same is possible for JSON and others.

You can just format you string the way you want it in YAML and Puppet will happily accept it.

For example:

```
---
hiera::input: |
  my string
  with newlines
  preserved
```

Notice the `|` after the `hiera::input` key name. It tells the YAML parser that to treat the following value as a block, preserving newlines and any other indentation.

Refer to sections [2.3](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760844) and [8.1.2](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/block/literal) of the YAML specification for detailed information.